# Many for loops sumarized into one loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am designing a highly inefficient magic square solver, it tells you the *number of solutions* to the 3x3 square. Essentially I have to fill each element in a 3x3 array till a certain number (say, 16) and then reset, move on to the next element and fill them both like a two digit number gets incremented. I have managed to achieve this through using 9 for loops, one for each element. But what if I wanted to do a 5x5 square, do I have to write 25 loops?

The for loop part of the code is below. Is there a way to summarize this and for-loop through the for loops so to speak?

```
for (sq9=1; sq9<17 ; sq9++) {
     for (sq8=1; sq8<17 ; sq8++) {
          for (sq7=1; sq7<17 ; sq7++) {
               for (sq6=1; sq6<17 ; sq6++) {
                    for (sq5=1; sq5<17 ; sq5++) {
                          for (sq4=1; sq4<17 ; sq4++) {
                               for (sq3=1; sq3<17 ; sq3++) {
                                    for (sq2=1; sq2<17 ; sq2++) {
                                         for (sq1=1; sq1<17 ; sq1++) {
                                              if  ( check_the_square() ) count++;
                                                            }}}}}}}}}}
```

`*** EDIT ***`

7 years after asking this question, I am a principal engineer at a large company and leading a devoted team. Thank you to those that were... gentle here. And thank you for being patient with me, your kindness went a long way

Comment: Oh.... myyyy.....

Comment: I would highly recommend taking a look at `std::next_permutation` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: Where you want to go????

Comment: Google for "recursive"

Comment: Do you realize that here you have 68 719 millions iterations?

Comment: And check_the_square() doesn't take any parameters??  Oh my!

Comment: Actually I had 16 for-loops but I figured it would scare people off if I wrote em all out :P

Comment: @millsj Thank you that seems to fit pretty well for this purpose.

Comment: @EugenRieck Is this what recursive functions are generally used for then?

Comment: The other way round: This sort of problems is typically solved by recursive constructs

Comment: You could unroll all of the loops! Do each calculation manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to generalize all this to arbitrary numbers of squares, but the first one that comes to my mind is to store all of the squares in an array and increment them like you'd increment a number written out in digits.

First, let's abstract away the number of squares and the range of their values with some easily editable constants:

```
#define NUM_SQUARES 9
#define MIN_VAL     1
#define MAX_VAL     16
```

Now, within whatever function you're doing all this, declare an array of `int`s and set them all to `MIN_VAL`:

```
int squares[NUM_SQUARES];
for (int i=0; i<NUM_SQUARES; i++) {
    squares[i] = MIN_VAL;
}
```

Now, how exactly are we going to increment the squares?  Simple: Add one to the first value; if it overflows `MAX_VAL`, set it to `MIN_VAL` and go on to the next square.  If it doesn't overflow, stop, and we can check the current configuration for whatever.  If all of the squares overflow and we move past the end of the array, we know we've handled all possible configurations of squares and we can end the whole thing.

What might that look like in code?  Something like this:

```
int i = 0;
do {
    if (check_the_square()) count++;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_SQUARES; i++) {
        squares[i]++;
        if (squares[i] > MAX_VAL) {
            squares[i] = MIN_VAL;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} while (i < NUM_SQUARES);
```

Comment: The real problem here is that brute force dont help. 3X3 will have more than 10^10 iterations, and 5x5 the impossibles 10^30 iterations....

Comment: Someone beat me to the punch. :) Just a minor correction, it should be `squares[i] > MAX_VAL`, since yours currently resets at 15..

Comment: @qPCR4vir Yea we get it, but I'm learning how to formulate thoughts with C... and besides you need a first step to optimize later. Read the first line of the question.

Comment: @jwodder Thank you! This is what I was getting at. Nicely explained too. 
Would the `check_the_square()` inside the `for`loop before the `if` if I wanted to check every configuration?

Comment: @ValentineBondar: No, the call to `check_the_square` goes outside the `for` loop.  The `for` loop just advances the `squares` array to the next configuration, and the `do`-`while` loop is what causes all configurations to be checked.

Comment: @jwodder Agreed there but wait a second. If the for loop always does a `square[i]++` then wouldn't:
`squares= {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
--after for loop--
squares = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`?

Comment: @ValentineBondar: No, because the loop `break`s if a square doesn't overflow.  Since 1 is less than `MAX_VAL`, the loop will turn `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` into `{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries that can generate all permutations, but if you'd like to do it yourself, you can manage it through an array of values, start at all of the values being 0 and end with all of them being 16.

```
const int SIZE = 3;
const int START_VALUE = 1;
const int FINAL_VALUE = 16;
int elements[3][3] = {START_VALUE};
```

And then define a set of functions to work with that array.

```
// Will return false when all combinations have been tried.
bool has_next_permutation(int array[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            if (array[i][j] != START_VALUE) {
                // We're not back to all elements being 0, so we're not done.
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Gets the next permutation.
// Increase the first element by 1, and if it hits 17, reset it and
// increase the second element by 1, etc.
void get_next_permutation(int array[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            array[i][j]++;
            if (array[i][j] <= FINAL_VALUE) {
                // Hasn't reached the final value yet.
                return;
            }
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it in a loop like:

```
do {
    check_the_square();
    get_next_permutation(elements);
} while (has_next_permutation(elements));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to replace your `sq#` and a small algorithm that computes the next iteration... Here you basically need a +1 operator to a number in base-17 written with 9-digits...

```
  char sq[9] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
  int l = 8;
loop:
  if (l==-1) goto end;
  if (++sq[l]==18) { sq[l--]=1; goto loop; }
  check_the_square();
  l = 8;
  goto loop;
end:
  ...
```

Comment: goto here is no problem: the first is a break, and the second a continue. The real problem here is that brute force dont help. 3X3 will have more than 10^10 iterations, and 5x5 the impossibles 10^30 iterations....